# Qt.QueuedConnection never sends message

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Why does this program not print anything?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

    sig = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def slot(self):
        print("received")

a = A()
a.sig.connect(a.slot, Qt.QueuedConnection)

a.sig.emit()
a.sig.emit()
a.sig.emit()
```

If I remove Qt.QueuedConnection, it works as expected.  I'm trying to see if Qt.QueuedConnection will automatically remove duplicate events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert with Python (or PyQt), but a queued connection only get's delivered once the application enters the event loop again, whereas a normal connection corresponds to a direct function call. So I guess in your case you have to wait until the application enters the event loop for the slot to be called (although I don't see any application object in your code).

**EDIT:** And I doubt that it removes duplicate calls, as Qt doesn't know if it's a duplicate call or a conceptually different call that should be carried out additionally.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It's too bad that Qt doesn't have a connection type that consumes duplicate calls.

Comment: @NeilG: How would this work though? What would be the criteria for determining whether a call is a duplicate or part of the logic? E.g. if a signal is running in a loop, ultimately incrementing some value as part of the overall program logic. Or are you referring to cases where two or more emit statements follow each other, like in your example?

Comment: @MarcusOttosson: I ended up writing a decorator that coalesces multiple emits.